# for in loop JavaScript returning undefined

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

```
let obj = {
  a:10,
  b:20,
  c:true,
  d:null
}

for(let key in obj) {

  //console.log(key);

  //console.log(obj.key); //4 undefined

  console.log(obj[key]) // 10 20 true null //work
}
```

why dot notation giving me undefined.

I`m newbie started learning js.

Comment: Because there is no key named "key" on the object, the options are `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` but not `key`

Comment: @mousetail key is the name of the for-loop variable, iterating on the keys of the dictionnary.

Comment: `obj.key` and `obj["key"]` are equivalent and not to be confused with `obj[key]`.

Comment: @BenjaminRio `obj[key]` vs `obj["key"]`

Comment: but key has a,b,c, and d values, I was expecting that it would be obj.a, obj.b, obj.c and obj.d. I`m I expecting wrong?

Comment: @MaxJoy — Yes, as all the previous comments have said, you are asking for `obj.key` not `obj.a`.

Answer (score 1):

The for-loop iterates over the dictionnary keys. Therefore, `key` is a string.

You can access value of key `a` element using `obj["a"]` (notice the apostrophes) or using `obj.a`(notice the absence of the apostrophes).

Since `key` is a string `obj.key` does not work (in the first iteration it computes `obj."a"`).